# Why drawable-hdpi-v4 is automatically generate in build\intermediates\res\merged and how to disable it

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my project's `res` folder, I haven't created the folder `drawable-hdpi-v4`, I just created `drawable-hdpi`, when I run app of debug buildtype from android studio,`drawable-hdpi-v4` is automatically generate in `build\intermediates\res\merged\debug`,and the `drawable-hdpi` does not existed, gradle moves all files from `drawable-hdpi` to `drawable-hdpi-v4`, I want to know why gradle do this, does anyone know about this? And how can I disable the feature.

Of course, my project has lots of dependencies, but I check every dependency that no one inlcude `drawable-hdpi-v4`

Answer (score 0):

[auto generate android studio drawble-hdpi-v4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBZqp.png)

[auto generate android studio drawble-hdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iDOo.png)

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
}
```

Here the `Common_full_open_on_phone.png` file auto generates if I delete the duplicate file.

Comment: So what is the solution to this? I have a png file which is not referred anywhere, expected proguard to strip, instead appears in this folder.